# Open and edit external file which has variable name in C

Tags: c, file-io, io

Quick question, since I only managed to find answers on the googlemobil regarding C++: Is there any way to open and edit files in C, where the file has a variable name?

Let's make it a bit clearer: I have a prompt, which checks if the user gives a filename or not. If no filename has been entered, the program automatically opens a `client.conf` file I created in the same directory; now this was the easy part of the if-else statement.

However, IF a name has been given, how do I make my program create a file `givenInput.conf` in the same directory, and send data to it? I suppose the r/w interaction would be the same as with the first case of the if-statement, using `fopen()`, however `fopen()` uses as first parameter const char *restrict filename, and I am trying to make something for chars that are NOT constants...

In C++ there is a way to bypass this by creating a separate (empty) array, pasting the input and then just adding the string suffix to it; also, it uses a C++ specific function (whom name I forgot, sorry ^^) to parse the variable filename....

Any ideas how to manage this in regular, plain good'ol C? I'm new to the C programming language, please be gentle for a newbie ;)

Comment: You might want to read about [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) (called [`_snprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93.aspx) in the Windows runtime library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send in a non-constant string where a constant string is expected and there is no need for a cast. So just open the file using a string you have constructed in whatever manner suits you best:

```
char filename[1024];

getFilenameSomehow(filename, 1024);

fopen(filename, "w");
```

You may not, however, send in a constant string where a non-constant string is expected.

```
const char *myConst = "May not be changed";
memset(myConst, 'X', strlen(myConst));  // Error! You may not modify a const string.
```

Comment: `getFilenameSomehow(filename, sizeof filename);`, leading to the same result, looks better to me. If you change the size, you do so only at one place.

Comment: I have found that `sizeof <array variable>` is error prone when refactoring. You extract a piece of code into a new function and suddenly that array is a pointer and `sizeof <x>` is now the size of a pointer, causing unnessecary debugging. In production code I go with `#defines` for array sizes.

Comment: This hit me once as well, you are right. But putting a `#define` for every place where the size of an array is needed can lead to confusion and unclean code as well. E. g., if I work with a local variable, I'd want to have a `#define` somewhere around that function, which I don't like as it seems not very clean to me.

Comment: You are right that an abundance of `#defines` clutters the code. Luckily, since the addition of runtime sizing of arrays the size will often be in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your variable to `const char *`

```
char file_var_name[100];

scanf("%99s", file_var_name);

fopen((const char *) file_var_name, "r");
```

Comment: That cast really shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the input using command line arguments to `main()` i.e. using `argc` and `argv` . Read [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm) for more details

Use `strcat` (present in `string.h`) to concatenate "**.conf**" at the end of filename.
Read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) about `strcat`.